# Messages not showing up in "Apps on this Mac using iCloud"

Tags: macos, icloud, messages, messages-in-icloud

On my iPhone 6s the **Messages** has been enabled to be accessed via **iCloud** :

[image: Screenshot of the iCloud screen on an iPhone]

Then I logged out of/back into my **AppleId** on the MacBook Pro with Big Sur.   But the **Messages** still does not show up in **Apps on this Mac using iCloud** under **System Preferences** > **iCloud** :

[image: Screenshot of the top-half of Apps on this Mac using iCloud window on macOS]

[image: Screenshot of the bottom-half of Apps on this Mac using iCloud window on macOS]

In addition "Text Message Forwarding" to that mac is enabled on the iPhone settings:

[image]

What else needs to be done?

**Update**    Messages that are created on the Mac are being correctly synced /viewable on the *iPhone*. But messages originating on the *iPhone* are not synced/visible on the Mac

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, Apple decided some apps should use System Preferences to control their iCloud syncing and others should it themselves. For Messages (and FaceTime) on the Mac, iCloud sync settings are located within the app's preferences, where you are given the option to **Enable messages in iCloud** and to **Sync Now**. This is the Mac equivalent to what you've done on your iPhone.

[image: iMessage Preferences Pane]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this. In my case the "Enable Messages in iCloud" had already been enabled so I clicked on "Sync now". The missing messages subsequently appeared

Comment: This is a helpful answer but actually is not working reliably on my Mac (Big Sur).  I have signed out/in to appleId, restarted Messages, hit "Sync now" again ..  Newer messages are again not being sync'ed. Frustrating